# Solrnet with Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, solr, solrnet

I'm new in SolrNet and Asp.Net also :)
please hit me with answer, HOWTO configure SolrNet for web forms.

[image: 400 http error]

```
 public partial class CreateIndex : System.Web.UI.Page {

 //http://localhost:8983/solr   
 private static readonly  string solrURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["solrUrl"];
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var connection = new SolrConnection(solrURL);
            Startup.Init<SolrProductDTO>(connection);
            Entities db = new Entities();
            var index = (from i in db.ItemBases.OfType<Product>()
                         where i.Quantity != null && i.Category != null
                         select new SolrProductDTO()
                         {
                             Category = i.Category.Name,
                             Id = i.Id,
                             InStock = i.IsDeleted,
                             Timestamp = i.CreatedDate,
                             Description = i.Description,
                             Title = i.Name
                         }).ToList();

            var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SolrProductDTO>>();
            solr.Delete(SolrQuery.All);
            solr.Add(index);
            solr.Commit();
        }
```

here comes my DTO:

```
public class SolrProductDTO  {

    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("cat")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [SolrField("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [SolrField("desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [SolrField("inStock")]
    public bool InStock { get; set; }

    [SolrField("timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

}
```

Please help!!!!

Comment: Are you running Solr through the console? (i.e. `java -jar start.jar`?) Check the Solr console log.

Comment: I'm using LucidWorks => Solr under Apache Tomcat.

Comment: can you check the Solr log and post the full exception message?

Comment: I have fixed solr fields according to my DTO and seems to work now.
I have a question: Does Solrnet provides auto configuration?

Comment: No, SolrNet does not write the Solr schema.xml for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error are you seeing? Also, you don't show your schema.xml (in solr/conf). I assume it has field definitions for id,cat,title,desc,inStock and timestamp?

Comment: I'm using LucidWorks => Solr under Apache Tomcat.
I didn't change schema, I thought schema will be changed when I invoke init.
Anyway, should I manually write my Dto's fields to schema?

Comment: Pretty late to the game but just to add a comment, in cases like this it is always recommended to #1 check that Solr is indeed running and #2 go to the Solr logs to find out the error. In a lot of cases it is a missing field, invalid type or some easy to correct error.